# Problem With My WinForms CheckBox Code

Tags: c#, checkbox, port

I have a requirement where if i click on  Checkboxes, then that corresponding port should be updated and these updated ports will be used in another file for sending outputs to these particular ports. So when i click on clickbox 1 4 and 7, then those corresponding ports should be enabled. In the place where the output has to happen(ie., class2), i run a loop, which will read from the port in a while loop(say), so only 1 4 and 7 ports which are enabled should run. The prob is, if i click on checkboxes 1 2 3, ie., consecutive numbers, it works fine, if i click on say 7, then the loop decrements and finally ports from 1 to 7 are enabled when only 7 is supposed to blink. ie., starts from 7, then 6, then 5 then finally 1 and all lights blink when only 7 is supposed to blink.

this is the checkbox condition:

```
    private void checkBox4_CheckedChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is CheckBox)
        {
            CheckBox checkbox = sender as CheckBox;
            if (checkbox.Checked)
            {
                Enableports[4] = true; or Enableport(4); // im setting that port 4 to true( Enableports[4] = true ) and directly entering the value in another API( Enableport(4) ). 
            }
            else
            {
                Disableport(4);
            }
        }
    }
```

this is the loop :(this is in another class)
bool[] Enabledports { get; set; } is the declaration for Enabled ports. 
void Enableport(int output); for a single one.

```
            for (int i = 0; i <= 12; i++)
            {
                if (Enabledports[i] == true) // API to check those enabled ports only
                {
                    Enableport(i);
                }

            }
```

here Enabledports is `bool[]` return type.

I'm not sure if I'm doing it the right way. I'm just a beginner and any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: @user403489: What types of ports are these?  On some connected device, or network ports?  And what are you trying to do?  Make it so if a check box is checked, a corresponding port blinks, and if it is unchecked, it doesn't blink?  Is there supposed to be any interplay between ports, like if you check one box, the rest are supposed to be disabled?

Comment: It's not really clear what the problem is. Do you know that `rr4.Enabledports` has the correct values? You talk about "the loop decrements" but you haven't shown any code which decrements anything.

Comment: yaa.. sorry.. i forgot to mention about the device.. the device is a IR device which can control the output to many output devices say TV or a Set top box. So if i enable port 7 ie.,enableport(7); then port 7 alone should blink so that device connected to port 7 should be enabled. but in my case, 7 blinks then the next time the port value decrements, ie., 6 and 7 then 5 6 and 7 till 1 2 3... 7. I donno why decrement is happening.

Comment: @ Merlyn Morgan-Graham  : Thanks for your reply. Enable port should enable the corresponding port of the device so this port will control that particular port o/p device alone. And there is no interplay between ports.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure that I've understood your question correctly, but I'll offer my best advice anyhow:

1. I think it is a bad idea to do "EnablePort()" in one place (the "loop in another class") and the "DisablePort()" in another (inside the "else" clause of the checkBox4_CheckedChanged_1() event handling method).
2. I don't understand why you have to do the "EnablePort()" inside a loop instead of calling it directly from the checkBox4_CheckedChanged_1() method, If not specifically required, I would suggest just calling "EnablePort()" directly.

Just my 2 cents...

Comment: As for ur second point, there is some other function, which will transmit the data through the selected port which is checked using the checkbox. So for the selected number of ports, i thought im supposed to run a loop. ie., if i select 4 and 9 then 4 should also work and 9 should also work continuously. But in my case first decrement happens 9 8 7 6 ... till 1. Please correct me if im wrong.

Comment: Then I think you need to move the "enabled ports" logic into the transmitting class, so all the GUI has to worry about is to call some enable/disable routine, and possibly query a list of enabled ports. But keep the actual port-logic together in one place...